# Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic'

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing the error Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the  following Content Security Policy directive:  "script-src 'strict-dynamic' , while executing the below code.

I am using the downloaded selenium webdriver  for chrome (version : 87.0.4280.88 )

My python version 3.5.0. Selenium version 3.141.0. May any one can help on the issue. some times the issue is not appearing.

Also verified the webpage is not used any CSP headers.
Any one provide advice whether we can disable this validation from selenium webdriver ?  and whether it is a recommended approach?

**Code used :**

```
            import json
            import re
            import imaplib
            import base64
            import os
            import email
            import pandas as pd
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            from requests import get
            from selenium import webdriver
            from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
            import time
            from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
            from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
            from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
            from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
            from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
            from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotSelectableException
            from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
            from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
            import xlrd
            import datetime


            try:
                urllogin = 'https://www.phptravels.net/supplier'
                my_web_form = get(urllogin).content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(my_web_form, 'html.parser')

                path = r'C:/Users/suresh.n/python/Files/chromedriver.exe' #make sure you insert the path to your driver here!
                options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
                options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/suresh.n/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data Copy/")
                options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
                
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,chrome_options=options)
                
                driver.get(urllogin)
                
                driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys('supplier@phptravels.com')
                driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('demosupplier')
                
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form[1]/button").click()
                
                time.sleep(3)
                    
            finally:    
                driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly the above error stopped appearing. Not sure on the exact reason. However resolved now.

Only getting the message for selenium chrome driver blue tooth  adator message.